# How to integrate admob ads in Unity 5.6.2f1

Tags: unity, c#, admob

I made the game space shooter. But i don't know how to integrate admob ads in Unity. I downloaded Google Admob ads Plugin for unity. But where i write the code don't know and how to implement it!!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no short answer to your long question, please study one of guide given below.

[**Ads Implementation in Unity Using AdMob**](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/ads-implementation-in-unity-using-admob)

[**ADMob for Unity By Google**](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/start)

[**Unity-Admob Github**](https://github.com/unity-plugins/Unity-Admob)

[**Unity Forums Thread On AdMob**](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/admob-unity-package-that-work-with-unity-3-2-above.173292/)